# How to load Images without callback hell?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, fabricjs, loader

I'm trying to load a couple of SVGs vie Fabric.js and push them into an array, to access them in the future.
I have this small function that "pushes" the pictures into the array. Everything works, BUT, because the asynchronous loading, I have not really a control where in the array the specific picture is located.
I tried to figure out, how to use the callback to wait for the next picture to load, but this ends in a very long and not very flexible program. 
There must be an easier solution. Could you please give me a hint.

Here is the function so far:

```
var axles=[];

makeMySvg('holes.svg', 100, 100, changescale);



function makeMySvg(urlName, posx, posy, callback)
{
    fabric.loadSVGFromURL(urlName,

    function(objects)
    {

            var obj = new fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, {
              top: posx,
              left:posy,
              opacity: 1,
              scaleX: 1,
              scaleY: 1,
              objectCaching: true
            });

            canvas.add(obj);
            axles.push(obj);
            callback();

    });

}

function changescale()
{
  console.log(axles.length);
  canvas.renderAll();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use promise and `Promise.all` to wait for all your pictures to be loaded:

```js
var axles=[];

var images = ['hole1.svg', 'hole2.svg' ];
var promises = images.map(loadSVG);

Promise.all(promises).then(function(loadedImages) {
  var posx = 100, var posy = 100;
  loadedImages.forEach(function(img) {
    var obj = new fabric.util.groupSVGElements(img, {
      top: posx,
      left:posy,
      opacity: 1,
      scaleX: 1,
      scaleY: 1,
      objectCaching: true
    });  
    canvas.add(obj);
    axles.push(obj);
  });
  changescale();
});

makeMySvg('holes.svg', 100, 100, changescale);

loadSVG(img) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    fabric.loadSVGFromURL(urlName, function(objects) {
      resolve(objects);
    });
  });
}

function changescale()
{
  console.log(axles.length);
  canvas.renderAll();

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Right now I do not understand you example 100% but I will dig into it. Promise at least sounds very promising.